# build gradle failed when adding jar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio for twitter posting demo and have some jar files to be added to `build.gradle`, I have placed those jars to the `libs` folder of my project and have added it to `build.gradle`, When I am trying to sync the `gradle`, it gives me below error :

**Error**

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':Demotweet:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name 'maven.aviary.com'
            url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name 'maven.aviary.com'
        url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('ion-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    // compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
    compile files('androidasync-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/fluent-hc-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpclient-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpmime-4.3.2.jar')

    /
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.4.jar')

    //end

    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile project(':google-play-services_libs')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'


    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':viewpager_indicatr')

}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    dexOptions {

    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}
```

I am getting this eror when i am adding below jars for twitter to gradle,

```
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.4.jar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in the dependencies, instead of adding individual `.jar` file into the build.gradle. It will includes all you jar file placed in the `libs` folder

Comment: Now i am getting below error `Error:Execution failed for task ':Stush:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/internal/widget/NativeActionModeAwareLayout.class`

Comment: Now clean the entire project and again build it. It will solve you problem

Comment: Awesome ,Actually i was facin this issue because of multiple unnecessaryjars in libs folder,I have put your code in gradle file and removed the unncessary files and cleaned the project and fixed..!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild project, and reflesh gradle

Comment: Right click on your project folder, find "Synchronize ..."

Answer (score 0):

you have to import them from android studio itself 
right click on your app then choose "open module settings"
, then press on the plus green button , choose "import jar package" 
, then browse and choose your .jar library
, then inside the " module settings " again , choose app from the list , then go to dependencies , and click on the green plus button on the right and choose "Module Dependency" then choose your library